# Detect and edit external links

Tags: php, jquery, regex, url

I want to say that I'm aware of similar questions on SO, but since my situation is slightly different I thought it would be better to open a new question. I did search for an hour, I may have missed something, if so please forgive me for that.

The problem: I'm developing a feature similar to facebook: user can post a text message which may contain a number of links, these may or many not be put in anchor tags, and may have different protocols (http, https, ftp,....)

I need to

1. detect these links and perhaps attempting to retrieve them (just like facebook). I guess this is the task for jquery?
2. I also need to reliably detect the external links and change them to mysite.com/external?url=thelink. Which, I believe, is that task for php (since I can't trust the input coming from client side right?)

Anyhow, with the links not guaranteed to be in anchor tags, it doesn't seem very reliable to use a dom parser (or am I wrong)?
I found a simple regex on the web (Im terrible with regex btw) which I think I can make use of (by adding a lot more protocols)

```
$strText = preg_replace( '/(http|ftp)+(s)?:(\/\/)((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?/i', '<a href="\0">\4</a>', $strText );
```

Can some experts out there who have experience in this task please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, this is definitely something you want to do server-side. First off, if you're accepting user input containing HTML markup, you should be sanitizing it with a good HTML filter like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). (This will also make their input easier to parse for more complex markup.)

This *should* be doable within a single preg_replace() statement, but I'd split it into something like this:

```
$hrefPattern = '/<a[^>]+?href="(.+?)".*?>/i';

$outLink = 'http://mysite.com/external?url=';

$offset = 0;
while(preg_match($hrefPattern, $text, $hrefMatches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset))
{

    $hrefInner = $hrefMatches[1][0];
    $offset = $hrefMatches[1][1];
    echo $hrefInner . "\r\n";

    if(strpos($hrefInner, '://') !== false)
    {
        $externalUrl = $outLink . rawurlencode($hrefInner);
        $text = str_replace($hrefInner, $externalUrl, $text);
        $offset += strlen($externalUrl);
    }

}
```

The [preg_match() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) explains that pretty well. We're basically just looking up each `<a ... href="">` tag, grabbing it's contents, reformatting it if it starts with `(anything)://`, and repeating until there are no more links left in `$text`. If you reformat the link, you need to `rawurlencode()` the link you scraped to make sure the new link is [valid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php).

The way Facebook scrapes content for it's link snippets is, I'd imagine, a lot more complex than that, but yes - you'd want to send an AJAX request to a PHP page that scrapes the link in question and generates whatever snippet you want. There's *quite* a bit more involved in that, though- you'll have to handle if the page does not exist, redirects to another page, has invalid markup, different document types, and so on.

Hope that helps!